# Autofilter with variable/cell as Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use autofilter function but I want to take the Criteria1 from the cell from another Worksheet. I tried to use the the exact range and also a variable. I become the error run time error 9 subcript out of range by the line.  Set GL = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("l7").Value. 
Is it even possible? Should I use another type of variable? 
At the beggining I am in worksheet("DE-CC") and the criteria I take from Worksheet("Sheet1"), cell "L7". Any sugestions?

```
Dim GL As Range
Set GL = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("l7").Value
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("AB1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("a2:ab2").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=GL
```

Answer (score 0):

This should Work:

**(Untested)**

```
Dim GL As String

GL = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("l7").Value

    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Activesheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=GL
```

Changed the Declaration and assigning of Value

You should Try this Also,

```
Dim GL As String

GL = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("l7").Value

    Activesheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=GL
```

Comment: Macro doesnt start. By the line Set GL = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("l7").Value I get compile error, object required :o

Comment: Ok, I delete "set", it goes further. I get now the error run time error 1004, AutoFilter method of Range class failed by the line ActiveSheet.Range("a2:ab2").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=GL

Comment: Try the Updated Answer.

Comment: I still don't understand the need of Inserting a Row, because you won't get any results in the filter, as the blank row that you are inserting will cut the filter